# What's the meaning of "With....looking on " in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

It was a good night for science at the 87th Academy Awards ceremony Sunday night. Julianne Moore won the Best Actress prize for her role in Still Alice, a movie that shines a light on Alzheimer’s disease. Eddie Redmayne took home the Best Actor Oscar for his portrayal of iconic astrophysicist and cosmologist Stephen Hawking, **with** Benedict Cumberbatch **looking on**, nominated for playing computer scientist Alan Turing.

What's the meaning of "With....looking on " in this sentence?

[The source of this sentence](https://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode/science-wins-at-the-oscars/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Look on**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/look-on) is a phrasal verb. The usage here is the second one indicated in the link: "to watch an activity or event without taking part in it."

[**With**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/with) is usage 12 here: "used to say what position or state someone or something is in, or **what is happening, when someone does something**" (emphasis added)

The sentence means:

> Eddie Redmayne received the award **while Benedict Cumberbatch** (who was nominated for playing Turing) **was watching**.